# Use pagination or search textbox inside header filter in aspxgridview

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using devexpress aspxgridview where i am using header filter with checkbox for filtering the data. It is working fine. Now some of my column have more than 200k records. For filtering this data i need to use pagination or search textbox inside header filter. This will be easy for the end user to filtering the data.

How can i use pagination or search textbox inside header filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your ASPxGridView header filter from checkbox mode to Filter Row mode.

There is already a nice demo from DevExpress showing how to use the filter row with ASPxGridView:

https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Filtering/FilterRow.aspx

However, having 2 lakh (2x100000) of records you may experience performance problems when filtering your grid. Because if when not in server mode the DX grid requires ALL data to be loaded into client side in order for those nice ASPxGridView filter, reorder and paging features to work.

In my projects when data set is too large to be loaded into grid with every request we have switch to server side binding of ASPxGridView to only 1 page of data at a time with paging applied at SQL level. It made the grid work really fast however speed comes with a price: those filter, sort and column reorder features have stopped working out of the box and we had to implement some of them manually.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Andrewes, Thanks for your quick reply. I need the header filter with checkbox mode because i need here to user can select multiple items and do filter. If pagination or search textbox is not available in the filter can i use focus item on hitting keyword like if some item is starting in H so when i press "H" keyword will the starting H items will get focused. Can we implement this type of funtionality?

Comment: @V.Prasad I suggest you ask this type of questions in the official DevExpress support forum: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ . See if you can get the expert advise there. Not sure if you need to have a paid DX subscription in order to ask questions.

Comment: Ok Andrews, I will ask this question on devexpress forum, Thanks for your helpful response.

Comment: @V.Prasad, you're welcome. BTW, I've noticed you've asked many questions in the past and have received answers but you've never accepted an answer. Why don't you show appreciation to all those who tried to help you and accept at least those answers which did help you?